# I am creating a youtube video uploading bot using selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium

I am decided to upload videos in schedule method. I selected the date input in youtube HTML Tag (using CSS_SELECTOR) to change the value like (Nov 15, 2022) using send_keys.[image: Date Picker]
[image: Input field I want to select]

```
<iron-input slot="input" class="input-element style-scope tp-yt-paper-input" id="input-5">
 
  <input class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="" autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" aria-describedby="" aria-labelledby="paper-input-label-5" autofocus="">
  
</iron-input>
```

```
date_picker = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'datepicker-trigger').click()
date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-input"]')
date.clear()
date.send_keys(z)
date.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Error : selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: I got the answer for this problem. Try `Webdriverwait().until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH))`